# Bad comparison of nonnegative value with -1

Tags: java, findbugs, inputstreamreader

FindBugs is reporting me that I'm comparing nonnegative value with -1 for the following code.

```
/* I get inputstreamreader from a org.apache.commons.net.telnet.TelnetClient object */

InputStreamReader reader = telnet.getInputStream();

char msg = 0;
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
while((msg = (char)reader.read()) != -1){
  temp.append(msg);
} 
System.out.println("Read Message = "+temp.toString());
```

But when I read through the `InputStreamReader.read()` documentation it says "***Returns: The number of characters read, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached"***

What is it I'm doing wrong here.. ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you should tag the language in question.

Answer (score 3):

`char` in Java is a single 16-bit Unicode character ranging from 0 to 65,535. It will never be negative.

As a fun exercise check what this prints:

`System.out.println(">>>>>>> TEST: " + (int)((char) -1));`

And figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

Reader returns `int`, which may be negative. But you are casting the value to `char`, which is nonnegative.

BTW, this method does not return *number of characters read*, but one character:

Returns: **The character read, as an integer in the range 0 to 65535 (0x00-0xffff), or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached** (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

The while loop compares a char to a negative integer. This should work:

```
InputStreamReader reader = telnet.getInputStream();

int data = 0;
StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
while((data = reader.read()) != -1){
    char msg = (char) data;
    temp.append(msg);
} 
System.out.println("Read Message = "+temp.toString());
```